# immutable map, adding a single object is a syntax error, 2 is fine

Tags: java, guava

When I am adding objects to a immutable map, I noticed this.

if I add a single object like:

```
 Map<String, Object> model = ImmutableMap.of(
                "post", post

        );
```

I get a compile time error saying that post isn't an Object.

If I do this:

```
 Map<String, Object> model = ImmutableMap.of(
                "post", post,
                "asdf", new Object()


        );
```

It compiles fine.  Is there a way for me to cast the post object to an object so it works with a single object?

Or more importantly, why does this happen?

Comment: What is `post` declared as?

Comment: Please post the exact error. I suspect it's complaining about `Post`, not `post`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is with type inference.

In your second example, you are using the `of(..)` method declared as

```
public static <K, V> ImmutableMap<K, V> of(K k1, V v1, K k2, V v2) {
```

In this case, the compiler will try to infer the type argument to bind to the type variable `V` from the usage of the method. In your case, that's

```
Map<String, Object> model = ImmutableMap.of(
            "post", post,
            "asdf", new Object()
);
```

Where `post` and `new Object()` are the expressions that will be checked to infer that type argument. The compiler will use the lowest common ancestor among the reference types. If the types are unrelated, that will obviously be `Object`. so `V` is bound the type `Object` and the method return type matches the type of the variable the return value is being assigned to.

In your first example,

```
Map<String, Object> model = ImmutableMap.of(
            "post", post
);
```

if `post` is declared as anything other than `Object`, it will fail because a `Map<String, Anything>` is not a `Map<String, Object>`.

That method is declared as

```
public static <K, V> ImmutableMap<K, V> of(K k1, V v1) {
```

The compiler again binds the type parameter based on the usage. You used `post` where a `V` is expected. `V` is bound to whatever the declared type of `post` is.

You can be more explicit and provide actual type arguments

```
Map<String, Object> model2 = ImmutableMap.<String, Object>of(
    "post", post
);
```

The [rules about type inference are extremely long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7) and some times hard to understand. You can try and read them if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration of `ImmutableMap.of()` looks like this:

```
public static <K, V> ImmutableMap<K, V> of(K k1, V v1, ...)
```

It will therefore return by default the inferred type of the key and value, and generics are invariant (so `<String, PostType>` is not a subtype of `<String, Object>`).

To force it into a `Map<String, Object>`, all you need to do is use (the ugly) explicit types:

```
Map<String, Object> model = ImmutableMap.<String, Object>of("post", post)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the compiler is inferring the generic type and using the most specific one (the declared type of `post`). Add an explicit cast to `Object` (or a type witness `<String, Object>` between the dot and `of`.

Answer (score 0):

This whole situation, in fact, is an unfortunate consequence of certain Java generics feature, namely the fact that Java employs *use-site variance* (contrary to *declaration-site variance*, like in Scala, for example), and also of that Java collection interfaces are very broad.

Guava's `ImmutableMap`, as follows from its name, is immutable - it is impossible to add elements to it after it was created. Because of this it is naturally *covariant* structure, that is, it is absolutely safe to consider, for example, `ImmutableMap<String, Number>` to be a subtype of `ImmutableMap<String, Object>`. If Java supported declaration-site variance and `ImmutableMap` was declared using it, then, supposedly, your code would compile successfully.

(There would be one problem, however. Java `Map<K, V>` interface is too "fat": it requires mutating methods like `put()` or `remove()`. This means that `Map` interface is inherently invariant. I don't know how would declaration-site variance work in this situation. Probably it wouldn't work at all.)

Anyway, Java has only use-site variance in form of wildcards. You can rewrite your code as follows:

```
Map<String, ?> model = ImmutableMap.of("post", post).
```

As others have already said, `ImmutableMap.of("post", post)` inferred type would be something like `Map<String, Post>`, and because `Post` is a subtype of `Object`, then `Map<String, Post>` is a subtype of `Map<String, ?>`, so this code will compile. Moreover, it will also prevent you from calling `put()` and some other methods during compilation.